# Exception In Performing the Reduce Operation in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new To Java 8 and in below example I have created a Map having keyvalue as String and value as ArrayList of integer.

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> mapLstInteger=new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>() {
            {
                put("A",Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
                put("B",Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
                put("C",Arrays.asList(7,8,9));
            }
        };
```

I wrote below code to perform the sum for arrayList elements against every key and was trying to store the sum value in seperate ArrayList.

```
List<Integer> sumLst=mapLstInteger.entrySet().stream().map(e->e.getValue())
        .reduce((inputLst, outputLst)->{
            int sum=0;
            for(int count=0;count<inputLst.size();count++)
            {
                sum=sum+inputLst.get(count);
            }
            outputLst.add(sum);
            return outputLst;
        }).get();
```

When I am trying to execute the below code I am getting below exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException    at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)     at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)     at
>   com.calculation.sum.client.Client.lambda$1(Client.java:43)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:123)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at
>   java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1696)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:479)
>     at com.calculation.sum.client.Client.main(Client.java:37)

Can anybody please let me know what I did wrong in above code>

Comment: Note that `reduce` is not transforming input to output as your code implies but merging two consecutive elements from the stream (two `List<Integer>` in this case).  `Arrays.asList()` creates an immutable array, so the exception is caused by the part of your code where you are trying to `outputLst.add(sum);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you're using the original `AbstractList` produced by `Arrays.asList`.
That `List<T>` abstract implementation does not allow adding or removing elements.

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

But anyway, back at your problem. You can obtain what you want **also** via a custom `Collector`, where you can *supply* your custom `List<T>` implementation, be it an `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, or whatever you feel like is better.

```
mapLstInteger.values()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collector.of(
                     () -> new ArrayList<>(),  // Supplier
                     (output, toSumList) -> {  // Accumulator
                         output.add(toSumList.stream()
                                             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                             .sum());
                     },
                     // The Combiner implementation will be called
                     // in case of a "parallel" Stream. 
                     // No need to worry about it here. 
                     // But in case, we would need to merge the partial results
                     (output, partial) -> {
                        output.addAll(partial);
                        return output;
                     }
             ));
```

A more succinct version is

```
mapLstInteger.values()
             .stream()
             .map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

That will correctly output `[6, 15, 24]`

Answer (score 3):

First you are using `Arrays::asList` which is documented as *Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array*, I think *fixed size* should tell you what you are doing wrong.

Than you are using an anti-pattern of creating a `HashMap` in place - by creating an anonymous inner class that extends `HashMap`, via that `Map<String,List<Integer>> mapLstInteger=new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>()....`.

Than, you are violating the specification of `reduce`, which is supposed to return a new Object all the time, but you always put into `outputLst`.

Than, you are creating a `Map` when all you care about is its values - create a `List<List<Integer>>` in such a case.

Even your sentence *I wrote below code to perform the sum for arrayList elements against every key* is not correct according to your code. I would just make up my mind on the actual thing I want to achieve and then try to do it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the following:

```
    mapLstInteger.values().stream()
                 .flatMapToInt(list -> list.stream()
                                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)).sum();
```

Added the filter to ensure you get no null pointers in the case of null Integers. As a general rule if you are forced to use a conventional loop inside of a stream you are probably doing something wrong. By mutating the list of ints to an int value we can easily sum as you see above.

Initially misunderstood the question thinking you wanted the overall sum alas here is an updated solution for the actual problem:

```
    mapLstInteger.values().stream()
                 .map(list -> list.stream()
                                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                  .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```